# How to change enemy size, speed, etc depending on mobile screen size?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a game where enemies are spawned from a library at random. Their size and speed are set to work on specific dimensions. However, these specific standards won't work well on phones with small screens. Is there a way to change speed, size depending on a phone's dimensions?

Comment: You can get the screen size (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions) and then set the size, speed, etc. accordingly. You can group sizes by small, medium, large and very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get Screen size with following code:

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13)
  {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
   }
   else
   {
     Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
     int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
     int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
   }
```

more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions), and change any thing with this information

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the environment, check out the System Capabilities class (screenResolution, etc)
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html

and for Flash settings, stageWidth and stageHeight may help:
 (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html).

However, if you're targeting both small and large screens, you may want to think about two (or more) sets of FLA files, since you can't set stage size on-the-fly, and otherwise you'd be scaling graphics, bitmaps, etc. to fit on either.

You can use Config Constants (ActionScript settings) to signal to the code which environment you're compiling.